# Independent assessment of a selected model

Tags: regression, machine-learning

The test data set is used for an independent assessment of the selected model, can anybody explain how this process works?

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked thread. Please 
read it. If it isn't what you want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.